# How to handle these nested subscription for route Param and API service?

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, parameter-passing

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  if (params.id) {
    this.formService.getFormFieldValById(params.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
        // bind response to form
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.route.queryParams.pipe(
  switchMap(({id}) => {
    return this.formService.getFormFieldValById(id);
  })
).subscribe(res => {
    // bind response to form      
})
```

Here you can chain each process rather than nesting subscriptions